# How to integrate terraform state into github action workflow?

Tags: terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-azure

I have the github action workflow outlining the simple process of spinning up terraform to create resources in Azure. What I am missing is how to integrate the terraform state file so that upon sequential runs of this workflow it should compare the current state with the main.tf file and only permit the net changes. At present if I run this sequentially, will always fail the second time because the resources will have already been created in Azure.

How can I configure the github workflow below to permit terraform state file comparison?, I have not found a single source that does this

github repo layout:
[image]

github action workflow:

```
name: Terraform deploy to Azur

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: "Checkout"
      uses: actions/checkout@master
      
    - name: "Terraform Init"
      uses: hashicorp/terraform-github-actions@master
      with:
       tf_actions_version: 0.12.13
       tf_actions_subcommand: "init"

    - name: "Terraform Plan"
      uses: hashicorp/terraform-github-actions@master
      with:
       tf_actions_version: 0.12.13
       tf_actions_subcommand: "plan"
       args: -var="client_secret=${{ secrets.clientSecret }}"
             -var="client_id=${{ secrets.clientId }}"
             -var="tenant_id=${{ secrets.tenantId }}"
             -var="sub=${{ secrets.sub }}"
                  
    - name: "Terraform Apply"
      uses: hashicorp/terraform-github-actions@master
      with:
       tf_actions_version: 0.12.13
       tf_actions_subcommand: "apply"
       args: -var="client_secret=${{ secrets.clientSecret }}"
             -var="client_id=${{ secrets.clientId }}"
             -var="tenant_id=${{ secrets.tenantId }}"
             -var="sub=${{ secrets.sub }}"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [add a backend configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/index.html) to your Terraform so it will store the state file somewhere externally, that it can reference and update on each run.

Comment: This was it, the reason why it was missed because I was simultaneously looking to secure the backend as well, ie. no having calls like "access_key = hardcoded guid", so I also needed to read up on environmental variables and storing secrets

Answer (score 1):

A better solution than storing the backend configuration elsewhere, when running in a pipeline, is to generate the backend configuration on the fly just before the `terraform init`:

```yaml
    - name: Setup Terraform Backend
      id: backend
      run: |
        cat > backend.tf << EOF
        terraform {
          backend "remote" {
            organization = "${secrets.TF_CLOUD_ORGANIZATION}"

            workspaces {
              name = "${secrets.TF_CLOUD_WORKSPACE}"
            }
          }
        }
        EOF

    - name: Terraform Init
      id: init
      run: terraform init
```

Comment: why is it a better solution for generating backend configuration on fly ?

Comment: It allows you to use variables when variables cannot normally be used here.  If you want to be able to reuse the code for multiple deployments, variable usage is critical.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Terraform cloud then this is what I've done

- Create a file per environment/workspace as an example below

```
workspaces { name = "dev" }
hostname     = "app.terraform.io"
organization = "terraform-cloud-orgid"
```

- Create another file called `backend.tf` with following contents

```
//Donot uncomment this file. This file will be uncommented only in Github Actions
#terraform {
#   backend "remote" {}
#}
```

- And now in your Github Actions add the following lines which uncomments backend.tf to reflect and select the specific backend file

```
      - name: Uncomment Terraform Cloud Backend Configuration file
        id: uncomment
        run: sed -i 's/^#*//' backend.tf

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
        with:
          terraform_version: 1.1.0
          cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TF_API_TOKEN }}

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: terraform init -backend-config=dev.hcl
```